# Json4S Recursive method parse needs a result type

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using json4s library in my scala program.

my build.sbt looks like

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" % "json4s-native_2.11" % "3.3.0"
)
```

in my code, i have a function

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JValue
class Foo {
    def parse(content: String) = {
      val json  = parse(content)
    }
}
```

but the IDE complains "Recursive method parse needs result type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scala compiler usually infers the return type of methods based on their implementations, but it has trouble inferring the type of *recursive* methods.

The message `recursive method parse needs result type` is due to this shortcoming. Your `def parse(content: String)` recurses by calling `parse(content)`. This makes the method recursive (infinitely so, but I'm assuming you were planning on changing it later). In order for it to compile, you'll need to explicitly state the return type, e.g. `def parse(content: String): Unit`.

I'm going to take a further guess and say that there is a `parse` method being imported from either `json4s` or `JsonMethods`. This is being shadowed by your own `parse` method due to it having the same method signature. If you actually want to call `JsonMethods.parse`, then you'll need to actually say `JsonMethods.parse` to clarify the ambiguity.